# Directory access is forbidden

Tags: apache, .htaccess, easyphp

I'm unable to access my root directory

```
http://localhost/zabjournal/
```

I have an `index.php` in my root directory that is not being processed.

This works

```
http://localhost/zabjournal/index.php
```

Im using `easyphp`

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zabjournal/

RewriteRule ^account/signin                 /zabjournal/pages/login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/validate               /zabjournal/pages/do_login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/signout                /zabjournal/pages/logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^account/register               logout.php [L]

RewriteRule ^author/submit/progress         /zabjournal/pages/author/progress.php [L]

RewriteRule ^author/article/([0-9]+)$       /zabjournal/pages/author/viewArticle.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/accepted-submissions    /zabjournal/pages/author/accepted_submissions.php [L]
RewriteRule ^author/new-submission          /zabjournal/pages/author/progress.php?addSubmission=1&progress=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/submission/([0-9]+)$    /zabjournal/pages/author/progress.php?loadArticleId=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^author/submit/1                /zabjournal/pages/author/submit_step1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^author/submit/2                /zabjournal/pages/author/submit_step2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^author/submit/3                /zabjournal/pages/author/submit_step3.php [L]
RewriteRule ^author                         /zabjournal/pages/author/active_submissions.php

RewriteRule ^reviewer/form/process/([0-9]+)$                        /zabjournal/pages/reviewer/process_form.php?form_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^reviewer/form/([0-9]+)$                                /zabjournal/pages/reviewer/viewForm.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^reviewer/view-submission/([0-9]+)$                     /zabjournal/pages/reviewer/viewSubmission.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^reviewer                                               /zabjournal/pages/reviewer/home.php

RewriteRule ^editor/issue/([0-9]+)$                                 /zabjournal/pages/editor/manage_issues.php?issue_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/issues                                          /zabjournal/pages/editor/list_issues.php [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/review-form/([0-9]+)$                           /zabjournal/pages/editor/viewForm.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/review-form/dialog/([0-9]+)$                    /zabjournal/pages/editor/viewForm_dialog.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/review-forms                                    /zabjournal/pages/editor/viewForms.php [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/assign-form                                     /zabjournal/pages/editor/assign_reviewer.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^editor/article/([0-9]+)$                               /zabjournal/pages/editor/viewArticle.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/articles/review/assign                          /zabjournal/pages/editor/assign_reviewer.php?form_id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^editor/articles/review/existing                        /zabjournal/pages/editor/existing_forms.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^editor/articles/review/new                             /zabjournal/lib/form_builder/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^editor/articles/review                                 /zabjournal/pages/editor/review_option.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^editor/articles                                        /zabjournal/pages/editor/accepted_submissions.php [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/submissions/download/pdf/([A-Za-z0-9_.\s*]+)    /zabjournal/lib/flexpaper/php/pdf/$1
RewriteRule ^editor/submission/assign/([0-9]+)$                     /zabjournal/pages/editor/assign_editor.php?article_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/submission/reject/([0-9]+)$                     /zabjournal/pages/editor/viewSubmission.php?reject_submission=1&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor/submissions/([0-9]+)$                           /zabjournal/pages/editor/viewSubmission.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^editor                                                 /zabjournal/pages/editor/editor.php

RewriteRule ^article/view/([0-9]+)$ /zabjournal/lib/flexpaper/php/split_document.php?doc=Report.pdf [L,QSA]
    php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
    php_value post_max_size 10M
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a "DirectoryIndex" directive that includes "index.php", eg:

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```